# Dropdown Box Inside Gridview Update Feature ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, edit

So I have a gridview in my webpage, At the moment the table returns values from an SQL table.

Inside my table I have 'Allowed Editing/Updates' which is updating values in my SQL table from the gridview in the webpage,
this functionality works fine, my only problem is... In one of the columns on the gridview I would like to have the option to
Select from a drop down box (as oppose to typing in a text box like the other columns),

The drop down box would be linked to  list that I have in SQL, I have tried all sorts of techniques and have searched endlessly
Online to try and do this, yet I have no luck,

I was was wondering if I could get some assistance with this....

Thankyou in advance.
Here is my aspx code for my gridview at the moment:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" border="1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" style="font-size: 0.9em; margin-left: 2%;" Width="85%">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactName" HeaderText="contactName" SortExpression="contactName">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactEmail" HeaderText="contactEmail" SortExpression="contactEmail">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" SortExpression="Telephone">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="jobRole" HeaderText="jobRole" SortExpression="jobRole">
                                        </asp:BoundField>

                                     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <br />
                                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" 
runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:saleConnectionString %>" 
DeleteCommand="Delete from IMContactEmails where ID = @ID" 
SelectCommand="SELECT  contactName, contactEmail, Telephone, jobRole, ID FROM 
IMContactEmails WHERE 

(ProjectNo = @PID)" UpdateCommand="Update IMContactEmails Set 
contactName=@contactName,contactEmail=CASE WHEN 

@contactEmail IS NULL THEN contactEmail Else @contactEmail END,Telephone=CASE
WHEN 

@Telephone IS NULL THEN Telephone ELSE @Telephone END,jobRole=CASE WHEN 
@jobRole IS NULL THEN jobRole ELSE @jobRole END where ID=@ID">
                                    <DeleteParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="String" />
                                    </DeleteParameters>
                                    <SelectParameters>
                                        <asp:ControlParameter 
ControlID="PIDvalTextBox" Name="PID" PropertyName="Text" />
                                    </SelectParameters>
                                    <UpdateParameters>
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="contactName" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="contactEmail" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="Telephone" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="jobRole" />
                                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
                                    </UpdateParameters>
                                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code inside my collumns with the TemplateField

```
                                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="False" border="1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" style="font-size: 0.9em; margin-left: 2%;" Width="85%">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactName" HeaderText="contactName" SortExpression="contactName">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="contactEmail" HeaderText="contactEmail" SortExpression="contactEmail">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Telephone" HeaderText="Telephone" SortExpression="Telephone">
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="jobRole">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLjobRole" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="jobRole"   DataValueField="jobRole" 
                        SelectedValue='<%# Bind("jobRole")%>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                     <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `TemplateField` in your Columns and add a dropdown list over there.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
             DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"               
             DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name" 
             SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Name") %>'>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </EditItemTemplate>

     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" Text=''<%# Bind("Name") %>''
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Add a sql data source and write the query to bind your drop down list something as below:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="Your connection string" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Name FROM dbo.Table"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Try it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, The code works thankyou, the only problem is, I can't seem to implement it onto an existing collumn, it adds the drop down box to the collumn I want, but then it adds another unwanted collumn onto the end of my gridview.

Comment: Hi. Which column do you want as a drop down list? Remove that bound field and add this template field having the drop down list.

Comment: I tried this, but once I do, it doesnt show the actual data in the collumn row on page load. It shows the drop down box when click update gridview, but in it the gridviews normal state there is nothing inside the collumn.

Comment: Can you place a demo some where? the actual code and the snapshot stuffs.It will help to understand better.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question to show you (Underneath 'UPDATE') Thanks

Comment: Yeah I saw it. Now what do you want to achieve? How do you want the drop down list to behave? Just show the jobRole as it is?

Comment: I'd like the field to show the results returned from the jobRole collum from the SQL table, but when the Update funtion is clicked, the drop down box can appear, where i will select a value, click save and then the gridview will change to that value in the field and the dropbox will dissapear.

Comment: Add an <ItemTemplate> to the TemplateField and drop a Label in there bound to the Name field...i'll edit the answer above

Comment: @DannyJones: Please try the updated answer as updated by Mr. fnostro.